# Value cannot be null error in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I'm wondering why is it returning a null value in the code that i made below:

```
using (var context = new MusicStoreDBEntities())
{
    var bay = (from g in context.stringInstrumentItems
               where g.brand.name == name.Text select g)
               .FirstOrDefault();
    context.stringInstrumentItems.Remove(bay);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The var bay is returning null. What have i done wrong? Here is the equivalent raw sql query that I'm trying to turn into an entity framework:

```
string queryGuitarItems = "DELETE S FROM stringInstrumentItem S JOIN brand B ON S.brandId = B.brandId WHERE B.name = @brand";
using (SqlConnection connectionGuitarItems = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["musicStoreConnection"].ToString()))
{
    using (SqlCommand commandGuitarItems = new SqlCommand(queryGuitarItems, connectionGuitarItems))
    {
        connectionGuitarItems.Open();
        commandGuitarItems.Connection = connectionGuitarItems;
        commandGuitarItems.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@brand", name.Text));
        commandGuitarItems.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connectionGuitarItems.Close();
        commandGuitarItems.Parameters.Clear();

    }
}
```

Let me know if the two queries are similar or not. I'm really trying to change all my raw sql queries into entity framework and this is a start.

Comment: run sql-profiler and look ad generated sql-code

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` returns null if nothing is found matching your conditions, are you _sure_ that you have a matching item in your database?

Comment: That SQL command will happily "delete" 0 records. Your `FirstOrDefault()` may return `null` when no matching item is found. So check for that null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not included your join in the linq query. Since you haven't included `Brand`, its not getting any records based on your `where` clause.

Since you're using entity framework, you might try something like this:

```
using System.Data.Entities;

using (var context = new MusicStoreDBEntities())
{
    var bay = context.stringInstrumentItems.Include(i => i.brand)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.brand.name == name.Text);

    if (bay != null)
    {
        context.stringInstrumentItems.Remove(bay);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The `.Include()` gets the related `brand` record from the database the same way the JOIN does in your SQL code there so you should have a record now.

The problem with excluding it is the same as if there's no matching records on either side of a join - no records will be selected by the query.

Comment: as an experiment, put a breakpoint on the `Remove` line and inspect the element. Given your linq query as the selection, I'll bet anything that `g.brand` is null or empty

Comment: your solution is giving me an error in this part : (i => i.brand) .. it says cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Did you add the `using` for System.Data.Entities? If you're using Entity Framework 6 it should work fine. Otheriwse, replace that lambda expression with `"brand"` to target the linked entity

Comment: yea i just figure it out few seconds ago.